# CakePHP Model to contain iteself

Tags: cakephp, join, model, cakephp-2.1

I need to join a model to itself... but I get the error "Not unique table/alias: 'Image'"

`Image` Schema:

```
id: int
thumbnail_image_id: int null
key: varchar... filename
location: varchar... s3 or local
created: datetime
modified: datetime
```

`Image` Model:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Image extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Thumbnail' => array(
            'className' => 'Image',
            'foreignKey' => 'thumbnail_image_id'
        )
    );

    public $hasOne = array(
        'Thumbnail' => array(
            'className' => 'Image',
            'foreignKey' => 'thumbnail_image_id'
        )
    );

    public function exampleFunction() {
        return $this->find('all', array(
            'contain' => array('Thumbnail')
        ));
    }
```

Running `exampleFunction` it gives me the error "Not unique table/alias: 'Image'". CakePHP builds the SQL like this:

```
SELECT `Image`.`id`, `Thumbnail`.`id` FROM `images` AS `Image` LEFT JOIN `images` AS `Image`.`thumbnail_image_id` = `Thumbnail`.`id`;
```

but it should be something like this... right? (notice the inverted `ON`):

```
SELECT `Image`.`id`, `Thumbnail`.`id` FROM `images` AS `Image` LEFT JOIN `images` AS `Thumbnail`.`id` = `Image`.`thumbnail_image_id`;
```

If I run both SQL queries above in mysql console the second works.

Suggestions?

Comment: Why the need for a join at all? What's wrong with just a plain select on `id` and `thumbnail_image_id` fields?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have used Thumbnail in both $belongsTo and $hasOne.

The Model will have no idea which association to use for the 'contain'.

Rename or remove one of your associations so they are unique.